# How to implement web api token authorization with asp mvc and javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I have a very thin ASP MVC application, that basically authenticates the user and render the views. I have a separate WebApi project where all the logic resides. What I need is to call the API from the views rendered by MVC using JS, but those API calls must be authenticated.

According to the documentation, I should get a token from the API by sending username and password, and then contact the api endpoint passing the token received in order to be allowed to access the resource.

It doesnt seem right to be passing the username and password from mvc to the view, so that the view can then contact the api to finally get the token.

What is the appropiate way of doing this? Should I request a token to the API from MVC (server-side) directly, at the moment the user logs in, save that token somewhere (cookie, session) and make it available to the views so I could call the api from JS using that same token?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you are trying to do but you should first have a look at this article [OAuth 2 Simplified: Browser-Based Apps](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified#browser-based-apps).

Now as you suggested, you can also post the username and password to your MVC app, let it talk with your Authorization server (probably your API) to get the access token and return it to the view in a hidden field, or a cookie... so your JavaScript can add it to the requests.

Hope it helped!

Comment: The article was really clarifying, thanks! I will go through it in detail to really get a deeper grasp on the matter. At least, it confirmed my suspicion that there was a better more secure option of sending back and forth auth info. Will keep you updated.